# Помогите найти скрипт каптчи

Tags: captcha, gd, php

Есть скрипт каптчи. Чуть ли не русским написанный(сайт и хэлп был по-русски). Библиотека - GD. Внешне выглядит как искаженные MultiWave буквы. 
Буквы одинакового цвета, цвет генерится автоматически, в заданном диапазоне. Та же фигня с фоном.
Ссылку на скрипт потерял, никак не могу найти.
Кто понял о чем я, прошу ответить =)
P.S. остальные каптчи тоже приветствуются, если они работают на сайте непосредственно(ReCaptcha, при всем уважении, идет лесом), но не являются ответом на вопрос.

P.P.S. скрипт был халявный

Comment: Я вот подумываю, мож свою писать начать, раз в Сети мало русских каптчей :) 

p.s. не ирония

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Это](http://captcha.ru/kcaptcha/) похоже на то, что было раньше?

Comment: Это оно и есть. ААА!!! Был же на этом сайте. =( Но не обратил внимание на старую версию(о ней речь и шла).